# Why redirect show blank page in model laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'd like to ask why the following code works, redirects normally, and data is successfully inserted :

CategoriesController :

```
public function store()
     {
         $data = Input::all();
        $category = new Term;
        if($category->saveCategory($data)){
            return Redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withSuccess('Category  successfully added.');
        }else{
            return Redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withError('Failed to add category. #ErrorCode : 13');
        }
    }
```

Term model :

```
public function saveCategory($data){
    $this->name = $data['name'];
    $this->slug = $data['slug'];
    if($this->save()){
        $category_taxo = new TermTaxonomy;
        $category_taxo->term_id = $this->lastCategoryId();
        $category_taxo->taxonomy = 'category';
        $category_taxo->description = $data['description'];
        if($category_taxo->save()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
            return "#Error Code : 4";
    }
}
```

Where as the following only inserts the data but then shows a blank page and doesn't redirect :

CategoriesController :

```
public function store()
     {
         $data = Input::all();
         $category = new Term;
         $category->saveCategory($data);
    }
```

Term Model

```
public function saveCategory($data){
    $this->name = $data['name'];
    $this->slug = $data['slug'];
    if($this->save()){
        $category_taxo = new TermTaxonomy;
        $category_taxo->term_id = $this->lastCategoryId();
        $category_taxo->taxonomy = 'category';
        $category_taxo->description = $data['description'];
        if($category_taxo->save()){
            return redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withSuccess('Category successfully added.');
        }else{
            return redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withError('Failed to add category.');
        }
    }else{
            return redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withError('#Error Code : 4.');
    }
}
```

Moreover, I'd like to ask a few related questions, does my code conform to correct design patterns, and where should I put the redirect, in the model or in the controller ?

Comment: You should absolutely never ever be putting redirect logic inside your model. I suggest you visit laracasts.com if you want to learn better techniques for Laravel

Comment: Please don't use `inline code formatting` for code blocks spanning multiple lines because they render really ugly in those cases. Use 4-space indented code blocks instead, for example by selecting your code and clicking the `{}` icon in the editor's tool bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for redirect:

```
1. return Redirect::back()->withSuccess('Category successfully added.');
```

OR

```
2. return Redirect::to(URL::to('admin_posts_categories'))->withSuccess('Category successfully added.');
```

Add your redirect login inside Controller. Even if you want to put in model (which is not recommended) use Ardent Hook function i.e. afterSave().

Comment: your first solution work as expected it will redirect back to previous route. but the your second solution seems not working correctly because if i change **admin_posts_categories** to other named routes it still redirect back to previous route not to my desired named route. anyway i should use model to business logic then give it return true or false , and controller for redirect function. sorry i am new in laravel. and thanks for your correction.

Comment: Happy to help, But I think either the routes were not properly setup or something, as I use both of the statement in my project and they works perfectly, anyways Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all never put redirect logic in model. Models are for putting business logic. Second thing check whether you have created route for `admin_posts_categories` in route.php or not and how you are calling views. If possible post your route code in question.

Comment: "never put redirect logic in model" +1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not putting redirects in your model. So the first solution would be the best of the two you have.

But back to your problem. It is showing a blank page because your store function is not returning anything. `return $category->saveCategory($data);` but as previously stated this method is not best practise.

An excellent tip would be to have a look at [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com), this will teach you everything you knew, didn't know and more about Laravel.